# 301 Redirect a domain to another domain, but keeping the subdirectories the same

Tags: domains, htaccess, dns, 301-redirect

Is it possible to configure a top-domain (`http://x.com`) (DNS/.htaccess/else?) to redirect to another domain (`http://y.com`), whilst if you navigate `http://x.com/subdir/index.html`, you'd see the files in the subdirectory of `http://x.com`?

**summarized**
how to:
`x.com -> y.com` (redirect)
`x.com/sub/index.html` -> `x.com/sub/index.html` (no redirect)

**Case use**
*I've got `sanderschaeffer.nl` and `iscs.nl`, which are both my business names. One is my own personal name, the other my brand name. When a user navigates to `sanderschaeffer.nl`, the domain should be forward (301) to `iscs.nl`. However, when one types (i.e.) `sanderschaeffer.nl/clientTestSite/` it would stay on that spot. So only the top-level gets a 301 redirect, but typing in the top-domain including a subdirectory will result in NO redirect.*

*For one saying 'Why don't you use the test sites in a subdirectory on the main site (`iscs.nl/`)?'; that's because I'm testing (temporarily) out a new server, where `sanderschaeffer.nl` currently is hosted on. :)*

Comment: It is possible. What part are you stuck on?

Comment: The start. :) - Wondering what is recommended: Using HTaccess or DNS and what lines are needed in either the DNS or htaccess file. :)

Comment: Just you just clarify... From the examples you have given above, you are referring to a "subdirectory", not a "subdomain"?

Comment: Domain should redirect to the new domain, but if one types in the domain + subdirectory (subdirectory, not domain, indeed) then it would stay on the top domain. So X.com goes to Y.com, but X.com/sub remains on X.com/sub.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you mean "subdirectory" and not "subdomain" (as per your examples), then try something like the following in the .htaccess file at `x.com`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/sub/
RewriteRule (.*) http://y.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Redirect (301) everything to `y.com` where the URI **does not start** with `/sub/`.

Note that this redirects to the corresponding URL at `y.com`, so for instance, `http://x.com/foo/bar` redirects to `http://y.com/foo/bar`. (Rather than literally only redirecting `x.com/` to `y.com/`?)

**UPDATE#1:** In light of the comments below, the following might be sufficient. This redirects `http://x.com/` (and only the root URL) to `y.com`. Anything else eg. `x.com/something` stays at `x.com`.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ http://y.com/ [R=301,L]
```

Note, however, that this does not specifically check for a *valid subdirectory*. Any path component in the URL will result in the URL staying at `x.com`.

If you specifically need to check for valid/known subdirectories then I would use a `RewriteCond` directive as in the first example above.

**UPDATE#2:** Another possibility is to check for anything that *looks like* a subdirectory ie. `/anything/` and redirect otherwise. For example:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[a-z0-9_-]+/
RewriteRule (.*) http://y.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This will redirect `x.com/` to `y.com/` and `x.com/file` to `y.com/file`, but will not redirect `x.com/subdir/file.php`.

Comment: As I just added in the comments in the OP, when a user types in X.com, then it would go to Y.com. However, when an user adds a subdirectory to the URL, i.e. X.com/sub, then it would stay on X.com/sub. I've added a case to the OP to explain the situation, Thanks.

Comment: That's what I assumed - the code I added above should do that. However, when you say "subdirectory", do you mean _any subdirectory_ ie. "/sub1/", "/sub2/", etc. Although if there are only a few then it would be easier to just add an additional `RewriteCond` for each subdirectory. Also, I assume `x.com` and `y.com` are separate hosting accounts?

Comment: X.com -> Y.com; X.com/ANYsubdirectory -> X.com/ANYsubdirectory - one method for all subdirectories of X.com. And yes, X.com and Y.com are separated hosting accounts, right now. :)

Comment: I've updated my answer with a couple more examples. I can't just think of a way to check for a _valid_ subdirectory in .htaccess at the moment, but maybe one of these examples will work for you?

Comment: I think 'update #2' will perfectly fit. As `X.com`, `X.com/home.html`, and `X.com/anotherfile.html` will get redirected to `Y.com` incl. respected files (as in example further), while anything within a subdirectory stays on `X.com`. e.g. `X.com/anotherfile.html` goes to `Y.com/anotherfile.html`, while `X.com/client1/index.html` stays there. If that's indeed the case, please reply and verify or clarify yourself. Than I'll mark this answer as accepted and the issue has been solved! =)

Comment: Yes, that is the intended behaviour with _update#2_.